# Mulesoft Design Center issues

Tags: raml, mule-esb

I am designing my System API using RAML 1.0 in Anypoint Design Center. Unfortunately, the RAML Library that got auto-generated using js2dt convertor from the response schema of my third party(system) is as huge as 1,45,000 lines. I have tried splitting up the library into multiple datatypes and referencing back in the library, but it didn't help either. When I publish this as a fragment to Exchange, and try to consume from my actual API Specification RAML, my Design Center is causing a lot of issues like.. the spinner on the top right corner just keeps spinning, the page crashes, the "Try me" doesn't appear. I am pretty sure this is because the design center is not able to handle this huge RAML fragment. When I try using a simple RQ/RS, it just works fine.

I am looking here for help on how to handle this situation.

- How to handle such huge RQ/RS in RAML ?
- How to improve the performance of design center ?
- How to turn off the preview in Design Center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to, generate a json schema from the third party model and refer the type as schema in the RAML. That was light weight and worked like a charm.